# Can someone explain this code and what HEAD is exactly used for?

Tags: matlab, command

Below is the code segment from a MATLAB script file. I do not understand the operator/command `<<<<<<< HEAD`.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
T    = [];
T1   = [];
T10  = [];
T20  = [];
T200 = [];
=======
>>>>>>> b877b50ba3f4af3500ca1c1b4f994cacc285fe00
```

Comment: @Wolfie that is git ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is not MATLAB syntax. These are signs indicating git merge conflict.

It means that you tried to merge different versions of the file and you should manually choose, which one to keep. Edit the file as you want it and commit.

https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/

Comment: This was helpful and the issue is solved! Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
>>>>>>> b877b50ba3f4af3500ca1c1b4f994cacc285fe00
```

are created by your version control system. I'm assuming you are using git for your code repository? This means you have a merge conflict at revision b877b50ba3f4af3500ca1c1b4f994cacc285fe00 (the hash of the commit). You either are looking at a file you tried to commit, or someone committed a file without resolving a conflict.